# creating a custom spl token 22

Tags: token, program

hey i made a custom keypair and want to make a custom contact address like my keypair. then I spl-token create-token and entered my keypair json and I got this "Error: "default signer is required, please specify a valid default signer by identifying a valid configuration file using the --config argument, or by creating a valid config at the default location of ~/.config/solana/cli/config.yml using the solana config command"" any idea how to fix

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error that you'll see across Solana and SPL tools unfortunately. If you don't have a default keypair configured, the commands will abort.

In your case, you need to specify some keypair to pay for the transaction to create the token. You can do this with:

```
solana-keygen new
```

And then funding your new keypair with an `solana airdrop` or by transferring SOL to it.

More information at https://docs.solanalabs.com/cli/wallets/paper#creating-a-paper-wallet